# Is summoner a viable class to play with?

Tags: terraria

I've noticed that with the new "journey's end" update there are new weapons. Is summoner a viable class to play with now or is it still based on summoning minions and then running away as the minions do damage? Because the introduced whips, but are those viable weapons to use?

Comment: What do you mean by "viable"? Summoning has been viable for quite some time now so I'm confused by this question.

Comment: There are almost no summoning weapons in comparison with the other classes and most of them are drops with small drop rates, like the slime staff. By viable I mean is it viable to do an entire play-through of terraria using almost only summoning weapons?

Comment: I'm confused by the "or is it still based on summoning minions and then run away as minions do damage", like that wasn't viable before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A summoner playthrough is perfectly viable, even in higher difficulties. Yrimir, a popular Terraria content creator, even has a series on his full summoner playstyle run on Hardcore.